# Accessing UI components of dynamically added Fragments

Tags: android

I have a simple class that dynamically adds a fragment to the activity

```
public class mainfilm extends FragmentActivity
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(android.R.id.content, new showdesc());
    ft.commit();
    //EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    //et.setText("hello world");
}
}
```

The fragment code is as below :

```
public class showdesc extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.showdesc,container,false);
    }

}
```

xml of the fragment showdesc is :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" 
        android:hint="stoyr comes here"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:background="#1919a1">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>
```

For a statically added fragment i can use R.id.editText1 and access the edittext .How can i access editText for a dynamically added fragment in the activity.
thanks

Edit :

I have got over this :
If you add fragment in onCreate() you can access its UI components in the onResume() method of the activity and not before that as by that time the onResume() of Fragment has been called and is fully functional.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        Toast.makeText(this, "onresume of activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
         et.setText("hello world dfasdfasf");
}
```

By this you can access the UI of the Fragment in the activity.

hope this helps

Comment: did you try : findViewById()

Comment: where did you added edittext dynamically ?

Comment: @eldjon yes not working

Comment: @DhwanikGandhi it is in the fragment that i have added dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.showdesc,container,false);
```

to this:

```
View RootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.showdesc,container,false);
return RootView;
```

Then to find your editText:

```
EditText et=(EditText) RootView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

Comment: the question is why findViewbyid does not find the edittext in the activity. also as per your code ,this et variable is in the fragment class whereas we are setting value to it in the activity class.